# Uso o TextWatcher para tratar o campo de EditText no android mas ele mostra R$ 12,50 como seria sem o "R$"?

Tags: android

```
public class MoneyTextWatcher implements TextWatcher {
    private final WeakReference<EditText> editTextWeakReference;
    private final Locale locale;

    public MoneyTextWatcher(EditText editText, Locale locale) {
        this.editTextWeakReference = new WeakReference<EditText>(editText);
        this.locale = locale != null ? locale : Locale.getDefault();
    }

    public MoneyTextWatcher(EditText editText) {
        this.editTextWeakReference = new WeakReference<EditText>(editText);
        this.locale = Locale.getDefault();
    }

    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

    }

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {
        EditText editText = editTextWeakReference.get();
        if (editText == null) return;
        editText.removeTextChangedListener(this);

        BigDecimal parsed = parseToBigDecimal(editable.toString(), locale);
        String formatted = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance(locale).format(parsed);

        editText.setText(formatted);
        editText.setSelection(formatted.length());
        editText.addTextChangedListener(this);
    }

    private BigDecimal parseToBigDecimal(String value, Locale locale) {
        String replaceable = String.format("[%s,.\\s]", NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance(locale).getCurrency().getSymbol());

        String cleanString = value.replaceAll(replaceable, "");

        return new BigDecimal(cleanString).setScale(
            2, BigDecimal.ROUND_FLOOR).divide(new BigDecimal(100), BigDecimal.ROUND_FLOOR
        );
    }
}

//Codigo do editText
Locale mLocale = new Locale("pt", "BR");
mEditTextValorParc.addTextChangedListener(new MoneyTextWatcher(mEditTextValorParc, mLocale));
```

Comment: O que é "tratar"? Por que você está usando um TextWatcher para dinheiro se você não quer o símbolo de dinheiro?

Comment: Na verdade so preciso de uma mascara para valor monetario em um editText, reais no caso que formate desta forma para salvar no banco de dados "20.99" se tiver algum exemplo de como fazer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Como foi comentado não há necessidade desse TextWatcher caso você não queira o R$. Mas para um maior esclarecimento o Locale e o método getCurrencyInstance tem grande relevância para a exibição do R$.

O Locale serve para setar o país ou região desejada e o getCurrencyInstance irá adotar a unidade monetária de acordo com o Locale.

Answer (score 0):

Altere a linha

```
String replaceable = String.format("[%s,.\\s]", NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance(locale).getCurrency().getSymbol());
```

para

```
String formatted = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance(locale).format(parsed).replace("R","").replace("$","");
```

Answer (score 0):

você pode ver esse nesse link
https://gist.github.com/webkoder/0acc7d00814d901af74dcdf7db2b4faf

```
// Uso:
// Declarar um objeto TextWatcher

// O valor do TextWatcher é o retorno da função Mask.insert, com dois parametros: string com o formato da mascara e a caixa de texto que irá receber a mascara

// ou o retorno da função Mask.monetario, apenas com a caixa de texto que será receberá o valor monetario

// Adicionar na caixa de texto o evento TextWatcher

// Ex:

// TextWatcher cpfMask = Mask.insert("###.###.###-##, editCpf);

// cpfMask.addTextChangedListener(editCpf)

// TextWatcher salarioMask = Mask.monetario(editSalario);

// salarioMask.addTextChangedListener(editSalario);


package [package];

import android.text.Editable;
import android.text.TextWatcher;
import android.widget.EditText;

public abstract class Mask {
    public static String unmask(String s) {
        return s.replaceAll("[.]", "").replaceAll("[-]", "")
                .replaceAll("[/]", "").replaceAll("[(]", "")
                .replaceAll("[)]", "");
    }

    public static TextWatcher insert(final String mask, final EditText ediTxt) {
        return new TextWatcher() {
            boolean isUpdating;
            String old = "";

            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before,
                                      int count) {
                String str = Mask.unmask(s.toString());
                String mascara = "";
                if (isUpdating) {
                    old = str;
                    isUpdating = false;
                    return;
                }
                int i = 0;
                for (char m : mask.toCharArray()) {
                    if (m != '#' && str.length() > old.length()) {
                        mascara += m;
                        continue;
                    }
                    try {
                        mascara += str.charAt(i);
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        break;
                    }
                    i++;
                }
                isUpdating = true;
                ediTxt.setText(mascara);
                ediTxt.setSelection(mascara.length());
            }

            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                                          int after) {
            }

            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            }
        };
    }

    public static TextWatcher monetario(final EditText ediTxt) {
        return new TextWatcher() {
            // Mascara monetaria para o preço do produto
                private String current = "";
                @Override
                public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) { }

                @Override
                public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) { }

                @Override
                public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
                    if(!s.toString().equals(current)){
                        ediTxt.removeTextChangedListener(this);

                        String cleanString = s.toString().replaceAll("[R$,.]", "");

                        double parsed = Double.parseDouble(cleanString);
                        String formatted = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance().format((parsed/100));

                        current = formatted.replaceAll("[R$]", "");
                        ediTxt.setText(current);
                        ediTxt.setSelection(current.length());

                        ediTxt.addTextChangedListener(this);
                    }
                }

        };
    }
}
```